# How to load uploaded image in Flask?

Tags: python, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm a newbie to the Flask and  trying to load a image which uploaded in my server.
However when I  trying to load the image, I always got `broken link image`.
I think there are some mistakes in my codes but I can't get a clue where it is...

**Upload.py**

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory, 
              render_template
from app.forms import image_upload
from app.models import Upload_test

app = Flask(__name__)
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'files/')
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

@app.route('/upload_test', methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload_test():
    form = image_upload()
    user_id = session['user_id'] 

    if request.method == 'POST':
       if form.validate_on_submit():     
          ext = (form.upload.data.filename).rsplit('.', 1)[1]
          filename = secure_filename(form.upload.data.filename + '_' + unicode(uuid.uuid4()) + "." + ext)
          file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
          form.upload.data.save(file_path)

          image = Upload_test()

          image.user_id = user_id
          image.filename = filename        

          db.session.add(image)
          db.session.commit()

          return redirect(url_for('index', form=form, filename=filename, active_tab='index'))
       return render_template("upload_test.html", form=form, active_tab='upload_test')
```

`Upload.py` works perfectly

**Load.py**

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory, 
              render_template
from app.models import Upload_test

@app.route('/upload_test', methods=['GET'])
def upload_test():
    if 'logged_in' in session:
       user_id = session['user_id']
       user = User.query.filter_by(id=user_id).first()
       user_image = show_image(user)
       return render_template('upload_test.html', user=user, user_image=user_image, active_tab='upload_test')
    else:
       return redirect(url_for('index'))

def show_image(user):
    user_image = db.session.query(Upload_test).filter(Upload_test.user_id == user.id).first()
    filename = user_image.filename
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
```

This is a part of **upload_test.html**

```
{% if user_image %}
<img src = '{{url_for('upload_test', filename=filname)}}'>
{% endif %}
```

I think I made mistakes in `Load.py` or `upload_test.html`(or maybe both)
Where am I wrong and How can I display a image correctly?